# Find the smallest number of linearly dependent columns

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b & b & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
b & 1 & b & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
b & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to find the smallest number $n$ for which there are $n$ linearly dependent columns.

Can we find $n$ using a method like Gaussian elimination?

Or do I have to check all the pairs seperately, then the $\binom{6}{3}$ possible 3- columns and so on?

Comment: The right hand side of the matrix being $I_{3\times 3}$ makes it immediate that all the other columns are linearly dependent on columns from that portion. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question...

Comment: So $n=3$, right? So always if we have $x$ rows and the $I_{x \times x}$ matrix appears, then $n=x$ ? Or have I understood it wrong? @enthdegree

Comment: That is correct. This is due to the fact that the column space of $I_{x \times x}$ spans $\mathbf{R}^x,$ so necessarily any other column you could come up with will be a linear combination of $I_{x\times x}$'s columns.

Comment: $4$ columns must be linear dependent. But I think, you have to check the pairs and triples because pairwise linear independence is stronger than linear independence, so it does not suffice to calculate, for example, the rank of the matrix. An upper bound for the required number is $rank+1$. Here, the rank is full, so I do not see a shortcut.

Comment: If $n=3$, you should be able to provide 3 linearly dependent columns. If $b=1$, the answer is obviously $n = 2$.

Comment: @Peter The rank is 4 since the $I_{3 \times 3}$ matrix appears?

Comment: The rank cannot exceed the number of rows, so here we have rank $3$.

Comment: So we have to check all the possible $\binom{6}{3}$ triples in order to find $n$? @Peter

Comment: I am not sure that this is necessary, but at the moment I have no better idea.

Comment: According to my computer calculation, we need $4$ columns, unless we have $b\in ${$-1,-\frac{1}{2},0,1$}.